# pycodestyle installed via pip3 but not found by bash

Tags: bash, python, python3, pip

I installed `pycodestyle` via pip3

```
pip3 install pycodestyle
```

But then the example goes

```
pycodestyle --first optparse.py
```

And my bash doesn't find `pycodestyle`.
I can find the exact path with

```
pip3 install --upgrade pycodestyle
```

which returns `Requirement already up-to-date: pycodestyle in /home/user2740/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and then do

```
python3 /home/user2740/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pycodestyle.py --first optparse.py
```

And I guess I could do an alias, but is there a way to have this happen automatically?

Comment: Have you added your user's local Python bin directory to path?

Comment: Check that there's an entry point in `$HOME/.local/bin` instead and as said, add that directory to `$PATH` then.